# Converting CSV file to shapefile - but want polygon not points

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a csv dataframe with the coordinates of a square.  I have converted the csv into a shapefile, but it plots as four separate points and I want the plot to show a square.

```
  Shape long lat
1   1.1   43  10
2   1.1   43  13
3   1.1   40  13
4   1.1   40  10
```

I have converted it into a shapefile and given it a coordinate reference system as follows:

```
test <- as.data.frame(read_csv("/Users/alan/Desktop/Test.csv"))
Coord_Ref <- st_crs(3035)
plot_locations_test <- st_as_sf(test, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs =Coord_Ref)
```

Then I can plot the shapefile using ggplot

```
ggplot() +geom_sf(data = plot_locations_test)
```

And I get this plot
[image]

How can I make this a filled in square rather than seperate dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a simple polygon from the data points, ensuring that the shape is closed (i.e. the first point must be the same as the last point). You convert the longitude / latitude columns to a matrix and put it in a list to pass to `st_polygon`.

Once you have created your polygon, you need to convert it to sfc using `st_sfc`:

```
test <- as.matrix(rbind(test[,-1], test[1, -1]))

Coord_Ref <- st_crs(3035)
plot_locations_test <- st_polygon(x = list(test))
plot_locations_test <- st_sfc(plot_locations_test, crs = Coord_Ref)
ggplot(plot_locations_test) + geom_sf(fill = "red", alpha = 0.1)
```

### [image]

**Data**

```
test <- structure(list(Shape = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1), 
                       long = c(43L, 43L, 40L, 40L), 
                       lat = c(10L, 13L, 13L, 10L)), 
                  class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: In my dataframe, I actually have 4 squares I have to plot.  What is the best way of altering this code so that it could plot 4 polygons?

Comment: @Alan20 If your data frame was called `df` and your columns called `shape`, `longitude` and `latitude`, you could create a list of appropriate matrices using `lapply(split(df, df$shape), function(x) { coords <- as.matrix(cbind(x$longitude, x$latitude)); rbind(coords, coords[1,])})` and pass these to `st_multipolygon`

Comment: `library(sfheaders)` can create sf objects from data.frames; specifically `sfheaders::sf_polygon( obj = df, polygon_id = "shape")`